# como manejar errores usando $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

He intentado de todo y no logro cachar los errores como por ejemplo cuando no hay conexión a internet o cuando no se puede realizar la petición con el servidor, espero me de a entender y me puedan ayudar,me bhan dicho que se pueden manejar los errores en el success, pero aún no se bien como hacerlo les dejo el codigo.

```
$.ajax({
        data:  parameters,
        url:   'createClient.php',
        type:  'post',
```

// Se ejecuta durante el envío de la petición

```
        beforeSend:function(response){ 
        $('#cargando').css({display:'block'});
        $('#exito').html('Procesando...');
        },

        //Se ejecuta cuando termino la petición
        complete:function(response){
            $('#exito').html('Exito...');
        },

        // se ejecuta al termino de la petición y está fue correcta
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            //Cargamos finalmente el contenido deseado
            location.href ="reparacion-iphone-cdmx-gracias.php";

        },
         error: function (response) {
            alert(error con la petición);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente `$.ajax()` no puede capturar errores como `no hay conexión a internet`, ese proceso deberias hacerlo antes de ejecutar el AJAX.

```
if(navigator.onLine){
  console.info('Conectado a internet');
  $.ajax(...);
} else {
  console.info('Sin conexión a internet');
}
```

La función `error` solo detectará si algo salió mal **realizando la petición con el servidor**.

En cuanto a "manejar los errores en el success", pues significa que tu servidor tiene que devolver algún código de error (en caso de que algo haya salido mal en el backend), dicho código de error será interpretado por tu Javascript.

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta amigo, pero tengo un problema, que aunque tenga un error, el success se ejecuta y me envía a la página de gracias y lo que quiero es que me detenga en ese paso

Comment: Elimina **location.href ="reparacion-iphone-cdmx-gracias.php";**

Comment: Bueno es qué lo que quiero aquí es que el cliente cuando registre sus datos, lo envíe a esa página de gracias y cuando ocurra algún error con la petición, simplemente aparezca que hubo un problerma

Answer (score 0):

soy nueva en stackoverflow.

Te comparto una forma sencilla de capturar un error.

```
         function cargarsubmenus() {
         $.get(
          '@Url.Action("Lista_menus")?menu='+ valormenu
          )
         .done(function (result2) {
          //si la acción se ejecuta correctamente se hará lo siguiente
          $.each(result2, function (i, row) {
              var $option = $('<label>');
              $option.val(row.Indice);
              $option.html(row.NombreMenu);
              $('#contenido').append($option);
              })
           })
          .fail(function (result2) {
          //en caso de fallo por algún motivo.
          console.log('Error al obtener los datos');
          }
         );
        };
```

Creo que la mejor forma de capturar los errores es mediante un SP, ya que administrarás cada tipo de error que pudiera presentarte.

Espero que te sirva de algo, saludos.